# Under what circumstances (if ever) does strcat() hang?

Tags: c, string, pointers, freeze, strcat

I have this code in a function in C:

```
char* root = "/home/OS/homework/user/honorsupgrade/HTML";
requestInfo->resource = "/bing"
printf("1\n");
int counter = 0;
for(counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++)
{
    if(root[counter] == '\0')
    {
        printf("True1\n");
        break;
    }
}
for(counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++)
{
    if(requestInfo->resource[counter] == '\0')
    {
        printf("True2\n");
        break;
    }
}
printf("2\n");
fflush(stdout);
strcat(root, requestInfo->resource);
printf("3\n");
fflush(stdout);
return open(root, 0_RDONLY);
```

...

Request Info's stuff, as needed

```
struct ReqInfo
{
    char *resource;
}
```

I have created two string (character pointers) in C, but for some reason when I pass these methods to strcat(), strcat() never returns.  This causes the program to hang.  I have tested to ensure that both strings have null terminators (so strcat isn't trying to concatenate more than it should).  The program will print 1 and 2, but never print 3, meaning it never gets past the strcat() call, as I am flushing the buffer to make sure that there isn't a problem there. \

EDIT: I've created the struct outside of this block of code, I'm getting the same issues when replacing "requestInfo->resource" with a char* resource and making it "/bing"

Comment: You need to allocate memory for the `resources` field of the ReqInfo struct, so you would write `char resource[MAXRESOURCE]` (or allocate it with malloc) Same for the `root` variable that you declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to write to `const char *`

Even though `char* root` is a `char *`, it really points to a `const char *`. And writing to that is undefined behavior.

```
char* root = "/home/OS/homework/user/honorsupgrade/HTML";
....
strcat(root, requestInfo->resource);
```

Code should  allocate a right sized working buffer instead.

```
char buffer[1000];
strcpy(buffer, root);
strcat(buffer, requestInfo->resource);
```

Answer (score 2):

Invoking *undefined behaviour* could in principle cause anything, which includes hanging your program. You invoke undefined behaviour when you pass a pointer to a string literal as the destination of `strcat`.

```
// root points to a string literal. This is immutable!
char* root = "/home/OS/homework/user/honorsupgrade/HTML";

....

// Oops! Writing to *root is undefined behaviour!
strcat(root, requestInfo->resource);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to modify a *constant* string. The statement

```
char* root = "/home/OS/homework/user/honorsupgrade/HTML";
```

sets up the `root` pointer to point to the *constant* string containing your path. The memory pointed to by `root` must not be modified, and to do so invokes *undefined behaviour*. The call to `strcat()` attempts to modify data past the end of the constant string data. It sounds like the compiler put something important there, and you overwrote it.

Answer (score 0):

In C the programmer controls and is responsible for memory allocation.

The code you provided will have an undefined behaviour, because you ask "strcat" (see "man strcat") to copy something into a place, which is not reserved (the end of memory occupied by a string pointed by 'root').

It is hard to say what you really want to do, but just to avoid the crash you should either:

```
char[<static_buffer_lenght>] root = ...
...
strncat(root, <something>, sizeof(root) - strlen(root) - 1)
```

which will make your program slightly bigger, or:

```
char *root = (char *)malloc(<size_of_dynamic_buffer>)
bzero((void *)root, <size_of_dynamic_buffer>)
if (!root) { <handle memory error here> }
...
strncat(root, <something>, <size_of_dynamic_buffer> - strlen(root) - 1)
```

which will make your program slightly slower

Have not used 'C' for a while, so some details can cause compilation warnings (anything within '<','>' you have to replace with proper text - of course).